# How do I connect a D flip-flop to a common anode 7-segment display?

Tags: flipflop, 7segmentdisplay

I have a circuit in which I have an SN74LS175N D flip-flop, which outputs Q and Q’, and an INND-TS40Y6AB common anode 7-segment display. My goal is to make it so that when Q is true, only the “a” line is on, but when Q is false, only the “b” line is on (these specific lines are arbitrary).

The solution I thought would work is wiring Q to b and Q’ to a, because since it’s common anode, b should trigger when Q is low and a should trigger when Q’ is low. It goes without saying that this didn’t work. I feel like logically this should work, but because of my poor knowledge of circuit design, I’ve failed to understand when and where I should be grounding/adding resistors to make things like this work. Here is a photo of my circuit so far:

[image]

The blue and yellow wires are the outputs I want for Q and Q’. Any help?

Comment: Can you draw a schematic?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. People can help you take the next step but your question needs to show a schematic, which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. The photo of a breadboard is of no use for that. Please edit your question and add a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: you are missing current limiting resistors on your breadboard

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems:

-pin 4 of your top 74175 is unconnected – did you mean to connect that to bottom 74175 pin 15?

-pin 14 of your bottom 74175 is tied to both CLR` inputs – maybe that’s stuck low.

-you have LEDs hooked to each of your Q outputs – they will clamp the Q voltage to the LED saturation point which may still be a logic low. Remove them or put in series resistors.

-looks like you’ve set a shift register (clocked by a 555?) After a CLR all Q will be zero, so how do you ever get a ‘1’ into the shift register chain?